# How to use an Apple ID when using hdesetup?

Tags: apple-id, filevault

In setting up FileVault in System Preferences>Security & Privacy, there is an option to use your Apple ID as a method to de-crypt the HD, once its been encrypted. The command-line equivalent is `fdesetup`, and on consulting its man page, I could not see the equivalent in its switches/options. Maybe I'm not quite understanding the implications of the terminology used in the man page, but I could not see how to do it. Does anyone know if specifying Apple ID decryption can be done via `fdesetup`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fdesetup doesn't support that feature. You can use other options such as creating or rotating a personal and/or institutional recovery keys but you can't store your recovery key with Apple using the command line.